# Avoid to receive the same topic that I send

Tags: qos, data-distribution-service, opendds

I've an OpenDDS node that's both a DataDriver and DataReader. The consequence is that if the node send a topic, the same topic is received from the same node.

Is there a QoS policy that avoid this behaviour? I want that a node can receive the topic from all nodes but itself.

Comment: By "the same node", do you mean "the same machine (but potentially different DomainParticipants)" or "the same DomainParticipant"?

Comment: I mean the same process for which I create a reader and a writer for same topic, same DomainParticipant.

Answer (score 1):

> I want that a node can receive the topic from all nodes but itself.

*If* you are in a situation where your data type for the relevant Topic includes an attribute that contains information about the source of the data, then you can use that attribute to filter on via a ContentFilteredTopic. Suppose that your data type has a field `nodeId` that identifies your node, then you can use a ContentFilter expression like `nodeId <> %0` and set the parameter to your own `nodeId`. The middleware would deliver all updates to your DataReaders, except for those that have your own `nodeId`. Check out [the DDS specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/DDS/1.4/) for more details.

Given that your application wants to ignore data coming from your own node, I would argue that your data type actually needs that `nodeId` as an attribute, because apparently that is information relevant for your application. So if you do not have it at the moment, you might have to add it.

If you are not allowed or do not want to add such a field your data type, you can also use another, more convoluted mechanism by leveraging the `ignore_publication()` or `ignore_participant()` methods. These are explained in the specification as well. If you want to go that route, let me know if you have questions about it.

Finally, there might be vendor-specific extensions to the API that provide you with easier ways to achieve what you are looking for. For example, see [How do I get a DataReader to ignore a DataWriter that belongs to the same DomainParticipant?](https://community.rti.com/kb/how-do-i-get-datareader-ignore-datawriter-belongs-same-domainparticipant) for a solution using the RTI product.

Comment: Ok I'll check the node attribute. I thinked to add manually in the topic the nodeID, but I've think that a similiar attribute can already be used from QoS.

Comment: What QoS you are referring to? As far as I know, there is no such thing in any of the DDS standard QoS policies.

Comment: I've read in [this document](http://www.omg.org/news/meetings/workshops/RT-2007/00-T5_Hunt-revised.pdf) the "Controlled Data Access" design pattern. It filter topic by entity or user ID. I'd like to know the opposite, to exclude topic from user ID (that's my ID).